# How to generate a new Job in the doPost method?

Tags: java, aem

I am having trouble adding the request object into a map that is passed to the JobManager to generate a new Job that is executed by a matching JobConsumer. The value of the JobManager is null (problem). Can someone please help me out with what is going wrong?

What I have tried so far,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobManager;
import org.gs4tr.aem.event.JobConsumerConstraints;

@Component
public class CreateSubmissionTaskHandler extends BaseSubmissionTaskHandler {

    private static final Log _logger = LogFactory.getLog(CreateSubmissionTaskHandler.class);

    @Reference
    private JobManager _jobManager;

    private JobManager getJobManager() {
        return _jobManager;
    }

    public String doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put("request", request);

        getJobManager().addJob(
            JobConsumerConstraints.SEND_SUBMISSION_DIALOG_JOB_CONSUMER, props);

        return null;

  }

    @Override
    protected Log getLogger() {
        return _logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be missing the @Service annotation on the class.

Comment: Either that or replace the felix src Component annotation with the official OSGi Component annotation ( org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component )